# How to conveniently type the xor (⊻) operator?

Tags: julia, xor

The 'xor'-operator in julia is defined by the following symbol: **⊻**
If I am not mistaken this is also the only symbol representing 'xor'.

**How are you supposed to type this conveniently?**
Am I supposed to copy or paste it into my code or remember the unicode representation by heart?

Comment: A small comment - you can also simply its ordinary name `xor`. That will not work infix, however,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Julia's REPL has LaTeX-like tab-completion, so you can use `\xor<tab>`. If you paste the character in the help mode (pressing `?` in the REPL) you can see how such character tab-completes:

```
help?> ⊻
"⊻" can be typed by \xor<tab>

help?> α
"α" can be typed by \alpha<tab>
```

Many editors have similar tab-completions.

Comment: What if I am not using the REPL but a Jupyter notebook or simply a source file?

Comment: You can do the same in IJulia, and also in most editors with their respective Julia plugins.

Comment: Can confirm this works in VS Code with the Julia plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There's a *very* old technique called [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) that offers two-character
substitutes for characters not available directly from your keyboard.
[RFC 1345][] (from 1992, though digraphs far predate this) offers a
standard set of mappings that includes some mathematical symbols, such as
AN for LOGICAL AND (∧) and OR for LOGICAL OR (∨). Some editors and other
programs support a digraph entry facility.

##### Vim

Vim offers an excellent and easy to use digraph input facility: [`:help digraph`](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html) will tell you all about it. You [enter](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html#digraphs-use) a digraph in input
mode by typing <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> followed by the two characters of the
digraph, so typing <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> will give you
`∧`.

The predefined digraphs mostly follow RFC 1345, and don't incude `⊻`, but
you can easily add your own arbitrary mappings. For example, my `.vimrc`
incudes the following (the number in the third field is the *decimal*
Unicode code point value):

```
digraph  XR 8891    " ⊻  XOR
digraph  NA 8892    " ⊼  NAND
digraph  NR 8893    " ⊽  NOR
```

Vim's digraph facility is fantastic, and I can't recommend it enough. Since
I discovered it I've become a very heavy user of Unicode mathematical and
other characters, and it's definitely saved space and increased clarity in
my code and documentation.

Note that if you need to enter the occasional digraph at a Bash command
line, using Bash's `edit-and-execute-command` facility (bound by default to
`v` in `set -o vi` mode, or `C-x C-e` in `set -o emacs` mode) will bring up
your current command line in your default editor.

##### GNU Screen

GNU Screen offers [digraph support](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Digraph.html) that could be useful if you want
to use them at a command line or REPL. It works very much like Vim, but the
default digraph entry prefix is <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>.

However, the list of predfined digraphs is much shorter than Vim's (though
also following RFC 1345) and there's no way to add additional ones via the
configuration file (though you may be able to use `bindkey` in some way to
hack in entry for other arbitrary characters—I've not tried this).

It can, however, be patched to add whatever digraphs you like, if you don't
mind recompiling from source. [This patch](https://aperiodic.net/phil/screen/screen-rfc1345-digraph.patch) gives an example that
supports most or all of RFC 1345.

##### GNU Readine

Though it would be most convenient for command lines and REPLs, since so
many of them use GNU Readline, it does not currently offer any digraph
support. I mention this here simply because if someone could be convinced
to add it it would be brilliant.

##### Emacs

Emacs doesn't offer a built-in digraph facility, as far as I'm aware,
though someone may have written one. (Or it would probaby not be too hard
to write one yourself, if you're a serious Emacs user.)

[How to insert unusual characters in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60487055/107294) offers some
suggestions on the pre-existing facilities, incuding using `M-x insert-char` to search for strings like "xor" and using `helm-ucs` or
[helm-unicode](https://github.com/bomgar/helm-unicode) to select from a list of Unicode characters. Both of
these are a bit more work to select the character than digraphs, though.

#### Visual Studio Code

As with Emacs, VS Code seems to offer no built-in facility for digraph
input. This could fairly easily be added as an extension, but I've been
unable to find one in Visual Studio Marketplace.

Currently your best bet is probably the [Insert Unicode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brunnerh.insert-unicode) extension.