# How to insert unusual characters in emacs?

Tags: emacs

In VIM I can insert unusual characters by using digraphs:

```
<C-K>{char1}{char2}
```

for example the `¿` character is represented by the `?I` digraph.

```
<C-K>?I
```

then I can define a custom list for digraphs in a separate file, but for now, I'm just going to post the content of that file:

```
digraph uh 601  " ə UNSTRESSED SCHWA VOWEL
digraph uH 652  " ʌ STRESSED SCHWA VOWEL
digraph ii 618  " ɪ NEAR-CLOSE NEAR-FRONT UNROUNDED VOWEL
digraph uu 650  " ʊ NEAR-CLOSE NEAR-BACK ROUNDED VOWEL
digraph ee 603  " ɛ OPEN-MID FRONT UNROUNDED VOWEL
digraph er 604  " ɜ OPEN-MID CENTRAL UNROUNDED VOWEL
digraph oh 596  " ɔ OPEN-MID BACK ROUNDED VOWEL
digraph ae 230  " æ NEAR-OPEN FRONT UNROUNDED VOWEL
digraph ah 593  " ɑ OPEN BACK UNROUNDED VOWEL
digraph th 952  " θ VOICELESS DENTAL FRICATIVE
digraph tH 240  " ð VOICED DENTAL FRICATIVE
digraph sh 643  " ʃ VOICELESS POSTALVEOLAR FRICATIVE
digraph zs 658  " ʒ VOICED POSTALVEOLAR FRICATIVE
digraph ts 679  " ʧ VOICELESS POSTALVEOLAR AFFRICATE
digraph dz 676  " ʤ VOICED POSTALVEOLAR AFFRICATE
digraph ng 331  " ŋ VOICED VELAR NASAL
digraph as 688  " ʰ ASPIRATED
digraph ps 712  " ˈ PRIMARY STRESS
digraph ss 716  " ˌ SECONDARY STRESS
digraph st 794  "  ̚ NO AUDIBLE RELEASE
digraph li 8255 " ‿ LINKING
```

They are symbols of the phonetic alphabet I frequently use in documents.

The question is: Is there a way to port the same symbols to emacs so I can use them possibly with the same letter combination "uh, uH, ii, uu" and so on?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, Emacs comes with three "input methods" that let you type IPA characters, `ipa-kirshenbaum`, `ipa-praat` and `ipa-x-sampa`.  You can see the description of them by typing `C-h I` (for `describe-input-method`), and you can switch to one of them with `C-u C-\` (for `toggle-input-method` with a prefix argument).

If you'd rather use your own combinations, you can define your own input method:

```lisp
(quail-define-package
 "my-ipa-symbols" "" "IPA" t
 "My IPA input method

Documentation goes here."
 nil t nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil t)

(quail-define-rules
 ("uh" ?ə) ; UNSTRESSED SCHWA VOWEL
 ("uH" ?ʌ) ; STRESSED SCHWA VOWEL

 ;; add more combinations here
 )
```

Evaluate that with `eval-buffer` or `eval-region`, and then switch to the newly created input method with `C-u C-\ my-ipa-symbols`.

Comment: I was entirely unaware of quail-mode until seeing your answer. I think I figured out the gist of it. But I'm unable to find any documentation on it. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any documentation either - I learnt everything I know by copying the existing input methods in the Emacs source code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I decided to go with my custom input method. If I add something like: `("uh" ?ə)` when I type "uh" it turns into the IPA symbol which is good but If I have the "uh" occurring in a sentence and I don't need the IPA symbol there then it is annoying. Is it okay to prefix them, something like: `("\\uh" ?ə)` so itt is only triggered with `\uh` ?

Comment: @ZoltanKing That should work. That makes it similar to the TeX input method. You can have a look at how it is defined here: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/leim/quail/latin-ltx.el

Answer (score 1):

`M-x insert-char` will let you interactively search for a character to insert. Searching for 'schwa' brings up a set of different schwa's to choose from.

For characters I've found I like to insert often, I've added keybinding for them like this:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-<down>") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "↓")))`

where I just copy-and-pasted the character I want into that string there. Looking at the docs, you should be able to create a keybinding using `insert char` with the name or the hex key of the character you want, as well: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html

Answer (score 0):

A nicer alternative to `M-x insert-char` is to use `helm-ucs` (or alternatively [helm-unicode](https://github.com/bomgar/helm-unicode)). This brings up a nice list of unicode characters in a helm interface. You can enter words of the name in any order (eg "alpha small greek") to choose from characters matching those strings.

**note:** helm-ucs takes a few seconds to load the first time it's used in a session, but helm-unicode doesn't suffer from this problem.